# Can an object be assigned to a list without instancing that object?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is an optimisation question.

I have a class with ~500 named constructors that i need to access through a list - the different constructors have to be picked at random based on specific criteria at runtime.

The constructors have the form:

```
stuff.s0 (){ 
    <data> 
    <generating code> 
}
```

The list is initialised with:

```
var stuffList = [stuff.s0(), stuff.s1(), ...., stuff.s500()];*
```

Is this creating 500 instances of 'stuff', or is an instance of 'stuff' only created when I use `currentStuff = stuffList[42]`? If it's the former, is there a better way to do this since only a small fraction of the 500 will be used during any one use of the application?

The data elements are declared as *static const* so they can be accessed without creating an instance, something similar would be good.

Also, is Dart good at garbage collection? So *currentStuff = stuffList[14]* would 'replace' *stuff.s42* with *stuff.s14* in memory, or does that instance of *stuff.s42* need flagging as finished with somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects are created immediately. 
All Dart objects are reference values, so assigning `currentValue = something;` will only change the variable to reference a different object.

What I would do is to have a list of *constructor invocations*:

```
var stuffs = [
  () => stuff.s0(),
  () => stuff.s1(),
  // ...
  () => stuff.s500(),
];
```

and then call the function when I access the list:

```
var currentValue = stuffs[5]();
```

This would not create the objects until you need them, and it would not keep them alive after you stop referencing them. On the other hand, if you need `stuffs[5]()` twice, it will build a new object each time.

Comment: Thanks Irn, that's what I thought and your answer is exactly what I need since the second use of an object would need to be a new version anyway. I can't find any reference to this online, though I may be looking in the wrong place.

It's a shame we can't use variables in names, stuff.s$n would save me from getting the computer to generate that list as well.